# Preposition to use with "Apply"

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence correct?

> This applies especially to your VAT return.

Or should it be **for** instead of **to?**

Comment: Without more context it is impossible to say. "To" is probably better.

Comment: Even with a very specific context, there's no absolute rule dictating whether you can / should use ***to, for, with, on*** or some other preposition in the construction *X applies [prep] Y*.

Comment: This is in the dictionary. This applies to your tax return. No for. A thing applies to another thing.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verbs "apply to" and "apply for" have different meanings. The sentence is correct with "to".

"Apply to" means to pertain to something or be connected with it.

"Apply for" means to submit an application to initiate some kind of official process.

Comment: I would also add that "for" can be used with the non-phrasal "apply" (or "apply to") to indicate a purpose or duration of time ("this applies for the next week", or "this rule applies to visitors for walking and running, but not for swimming").  This use also means something different than "to", though, and is not interchangeable.

Comment: Well, in that case I'd analyze it less as a phrasal verb, more as a regular intransitive verb modified by a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. just wanted to point out that "apply" and "for" can be used together this way as well, so "apply for" isn't necessarily always the phrasal verb form.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is certainly correct as-is, but `for` would be just as good in some cases, such as if the main subject is not VAT. If this is part of a manual for VAT returns, then `to` is probably better, but the full context would make things clearer.